# Elegant way for concatenation

Tags: sql-server, concat

I am looking for the most elegant solution to prevent the addition of the last/ final separator ';' after the last row.

For example the result should be

> 'Peter,Paul,Jill'

instead of

> 'Peter,Paul,Jill,'

```
DECLARE @p varchar(max) = '';
SELECT @P = @P + col2 +',' FROM tab1 WHERE coli = 1
RETURN @P
```

The solution

```
RETURN LEFT(@P, LEN(@P) -1);
```

works only if @P is long enough and so is not a solution...

How can I solve this elegant and reliable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `stuff` function, we can also try the `isnull` trick (reusing code already done by Scott):

```
Declare @Table table (StringText varchar(100))
DECLARE @ConcatString varchar(100)

insert into @Table values('Tom'), ('Dick'), ('Harry')

SELECT @ConcatString = isnull(@ConcatString + ',', '') + StringText
from @Table

print @ConcatString
```

Answer (score 2):

I think a lot of people solve this with the [`STUFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) function.  I found an example from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196371/sql-query-concatenating-results-into-one-string) and adapted it.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @Table TABLE (StringText VARCHAR(100))
DECLARE @ConcatString VARCHAR(100)

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('Tom')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('Dick')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('Harry')

SELECT @ConcatString = STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + StringText
            FROM @Table
            ORDER BY StringText
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

PRINT @ConcatString
```

As Dan Guzman points out in the comments, specifying TYPE and value method avoids entity references in the resultant string for special characters like ampersand.

Comment: With FOR XML, I suggest specifying TYPE and value method to avoid entity references in the resultant string for special characters like ampersand: `FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(MAX)')`

Comment: @DanGuzman - thanks for the tip on using TYPE and value to avoid entity references in the resultant string for special characters.